# Checking if elements in my dataframe columns have the same type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I'm using Python and work with a dataframe `df`. When trying to check if for all columns, each row has the same type I wrote the following lines :

```
a=0
first_object = df.loc[df.index[0]]
for column in df: 
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if type(df[column][i]) != type(first_object[column]):
            a+=1
print(a)
```

The error I got is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/adsml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/adsml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/adsml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 155

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/xb/74q_24bx0rxgqc6gtd6ksn7c0000gn/T/ipykernel_25626/3160699232.py in <module>
      3 for column in df:
      4     for i in range(0,len(df)):
----> 5         if type(df[column][i]) != type(first_object[column]):
      6             a+=1

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/adsml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/adsml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/adsml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 155
```

I am confused as both `type(df[column][i])` and `type(first_object[column])` works separately. I tried it with matching types and non-matching types, and `True` and `False` were returned as expected. So I don't understand why my code is not working.

Comment: Your mistake is there: `df[column][i]`. When you make that call, I think pandas assume you mean `df[column].loc[i]`, so it expects `i` to be a valid index name. If you want the ith row instead, use `df[column].iloc[i]`.

Comment: Or better, `df.loc[i, column]` with `i` the real index (not a range). See below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of columns that have a unique type of object.

You can use:

```
df.applymap(type).nunique().eq(1).sum()
```

##### fixing your code:

I wouldn't use a loop in real-life!

```
a=0
first_object = df.iloc[0]
for column in df: 
    for i in df.index:
        if type(df.loc[i, column]) != type(first_object[column]):
            a+=1
```

The vectorial equivalent (counting the values that differ from your first row) would be:

```
df2 = df.applymap(type)
out = df2.ne(df2.iloc[0]).sum().sum()
```

Comment: Hi! This totally solve my problem, thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer. However I'm still interested to know why I got a mistake, do you think anything looks wrong in my code?

Comment: (Sorry, I can't upvote yet...)

Comment: I added a fix of your code and realized it was rather counting the values that differed from the first row

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer!!